# Use another jQuery form validation plugin in Yii

Tags: jquery, yii, validation

i start with a registration form with user input validation. All works fine. But now  want to use another jquery Plugin for the form validation, becouse i want another style of showing the errormessages.

How can i do this?

btw very nice framework :)

Greats
Thomas

Comment: what type of error message do you want to show? You can write custom css for the error elements to show them as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery Walidate: http://jquery.dop-trois.org/walidate/

And to create a custom error message (simple):

HTML:

```
<div id="error-message" style="display: none">
    Please fill out all required fields!
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('form').walidate({
    doIfSomethingIsInvalid: function() {
        // will be executed after clicking the submit-button
        // if a required input is empty.
        $('#error-message').fadeIn().delay(2500).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Or for each element:

```
$('.mail').walidate('validate', {
    valid: function() {
        $(this).next('.errorMsg').remove();
    },
    invalid: function() {
        $(this).after('<em class="errorMsg">Please enter a valid e-mail adress</em>');
    }
);
```